# /var/log/messages spammed with POLLERR messages

Tags: syslog, opensuse, syslog-ng

I've started seeing /var/log/messages growing in size indefinitely with these lines:

`Aug  1 12:47:27 linux-jblp syslog-ng[1947]: POLLERR occurred while idle; fd='16'`

Process 1947 is this:

`root      1947     1  1 12:45 ?        00:00:03 /sbin/syslog-ng -a /var/lib/dhcp/dev/log -a /var/lib/named/dev/log`

And `/proc/1947/fd` doesn't have a file `16`.

I have no idea why this started happening or what this means in practice. Any ideas?

Here's `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf`: http://pastebin.com/rMF7q3Br

Comment: https://lists.balabit.hu/pipermail/syslog-ng/2010-July/014425.html

Comment: http://notes.benv.junerules.com/syslog-ng-pollerr-occurred-while-idle-fdnn/

Comment: Seen those before I came here. I'm afraid it doesn't tell me much on how to fix this.

Comment: Please show us the `syslog-ng` configuration file?

Comment: @quanta: added.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when the other end of a pipe closed down w/o syslog-ng knowing about it. According to your syslog-ng.conf file you are spawning /usr/sbin/sshguard as a log destination. Is this process still running when you are getting those errors?

Comment: It's not running.

Comment: Right. So, that's where you have to look at. Does the process start up when you restart syslog-ng and at what point does it disappear?